# Relationship query issue between case and a custom object

Tags: apex, relationships

I have a Case object related to a Custom Object work part (Api Name- Work_Part__c ). Case is the parent object. I am trying to fetch all the work parts related to a case using below query

```
List<Case> c = new List<Case> ();
c =[Select Id from Case where Id ='5006F00001tjI5S'];
system.debug('size' + c.size());
system.debug('Workparts' + c[0].work_parts__r.size());
```

In the debug log, size is 1 , but the Workparts value is 0. 
Though the case with Id '5006F00001tjI5S' has 2 work parts as the related list. 
I triple checked relationship name is work_parts__r . Not sure, what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any data you wish to access in Apex, you must include the child objects in your query. Specifically, you must perform a SOQL [parent-child query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using) using the relationship name `Work_Parts__r`:

```
c = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, ... other fields ... FROM Work_Parts__r)
     FROM Case
     WHERE Id = ...];
```

Only then can you access `c[0].Work_Parts__r` as a `List`. Note that the `size()` of `c` is the number of `Case` records, while the `size()` of `c[0].Work_Parts__r` is the number of `Work_Part__c` records associated with the first result `Case`.